# find the output mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table name T1 having only one Column name Col1 having rows –

```
Col1
a
b
c
```

And another table name T2 also having only one Column name Col1 having rows –

```
Col1
x
y
z
```

Now I want record like

```
Col1--Col2
a------x
b------y
c------z
```

I am using mysql.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How do u calculate, A should come with X in output, in other words what are the rules for joining?

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what your table structure looks like or the result you want. Could you restate the question?

Comment: Be clear with your question first

Comment: there is no constraints in the table like primary key.

Comment: can we use rowid, rownum kind of things in sql. since i am new in mysql so i don't have any idea. could u please show me the way.

Comment: What if both table have different number of rows.....

Comment: question is very much clear. our output should be like below.
Row 1 - A,X
Row 2 - B,Y
Row 3 - C,Z

and suppose like both the tables have the same number of rows.

Comment: Hasn't @Richard aka cyberkiwi answered your question? You haven't marked any answer as accepted yet.

Comment: **bold** Richard has answered my query. Thanks Richard.

Answer (score 3):

```
create table T1(col1 varchar(10));
insert T1 values ('a'),('b'),('c');
create table T2(col2 varchar(10));
insert T2 values ('x'),('y'),('z');

select A.col1, B.col2 from
(select @r:=@r+1 rownum, col1 from (select @r:=0) initvar, T1) A,
(select @s:=@s+1 rownum, col2 from (select @s:=0) initvar, T2) B
where A.rownum=B.rownum
```

Because there is no ORDER BY clause, you are depending on luck and convention for the row numbering to be according to the order inserted. *It may not always be the case.*

Comment: Thanks Richard. Actually I was using the same query but forget to initialize r and s variables. So my result was Empty set.

Thank You Very Much.

Comment: @user306689 - Glad to help (you were 90% there). FYI, the convention on this site is to tick an answer to help highlight that it is the right/best solution to a question.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if you want to join the tables to get row results like this:

- Row 1 - A,X
- Row 2 - B,Y
- Row 3 - C,Z

..then you will have to add a common field that you can JOIN the two tables on.

If you want to be able to return results from both tables like this:

- Row 1 - A
- Row 2 - B
- Row 3 - C
- Row 4 - X
- Row 5 - Y
- Row 6 - Z

.. then you will need to use a UNION:

```
(SELECT Col1 FROM T1) UNION (SELECT Col1 FROM T2)
```

Comment: thanks for responding. But I need the result first one. 
Row 1 - A, X Row 2 - B, Y Row 3 - C, Z
and I have no choice to alter the table.